# i3wm - show tabs bar only if `mod` key is pressed

Tags: i3

`i3wm` - how to show tabs bar only if `meta` key is pressed?

The same as status bar if `mode hide` is in bar config.

Comment: *i3* does not have a "tabs bar" and it seems that you do not actually mean the "status bar". Could you please specify, what you mean by "tabs bar"? For example do you use *i3* in conjunction with some DE? Or maybe you mean the window titles when using tabbed layout?

Comment: You are wrong. There is tabs mode - list of fullscreen opened apps, by default -[ mod +w]. Tabs bar by default at the top of screen No any de.

Comment: That is the tabbed layout I mentioned in my previous comment (I added it as an afterthought, so it is possible you did not see it before answering.) It is essentially just a different way to organize windows (in contrast to split or stacked layout) and has nothing to do with fullscreen as you can also use it in subcontainers.

Comment: So, there isn't any way to hide tabs titles, right?

Comment: Not in the way you wanted, sorry. I put it in an answer as it got to long for just a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "tabs bar" is just the way *i3* shows titles of multiple windows when they are organized in a *tabbed container*. It is a part of the window decoration and not really a bar in the same sense as the *status bar*.

While it is possible to remove the *title bar* from windows in *split containers*, *i3* will always show the titles in *stacked* or *tabbed* layouts.

The only way to reduce impact on screen estate of the title bar in *tabbed layouts* is to reduce the font size. But this requires to edit and reload the configuration. So it is probably not something one should bind to a regularly pressed key.

There is also the possibility to make the current window truly fullscreen. By default the command `fullscreen toggle` is bound to <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>. The drawback here is that you need to leave the fullscreen mode by pressing <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> again in order to be able to reach other windows.

Comment: And I think that here should be feature request to i3 developer.

Comment: There was: [#1391](https://github.com/i3/i3/issues/1391) and also a duplicate [#1667](https://github.com/i3/i3/issues/1667).